# Thompson's construction, The empty-expression

Tags: finite-automata, compilers

Why this case exists in Thompson's construction algorithm?
[image]

Isn't just a special case of:
[image]
where the symbol **a** is replaced by **ϵ**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a special case since $a$ is a symbol of the alphabet whereas $\epsilon$ is a symbol representing the empty word. However, you could lump the two cases together if you wish.

It all boils down to your recursive definition of regular expression. Most definitions will have three "axioms": $a$ for $a \in \Sigma$, $\epsilon$, and $\emptyset$. This necessitates three different base cases in the construction.

Comment: Does this difference have impact on **implementing** the algorithm?

Comment: That depends on the implementation. It really depends on how you represent (parsed) regular expressions and NFAs. Such details are off-topic here - you can figure them out on your own.